# Replace http_post_fields to CURL for PHP 7+

Tags: php, html, curl, post

There's an outdated guide for caching torrent files on itorrents.org. I'm trying to update the script to work with PHP 7+.

This is their automation

```
<?php
    $files = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'torrent',            // Don't change
            'type' => 'application/x-bittorrent',
            'file' => 'my.torrent'          // Full path for file to upload
        )
    );

    $http_resp = http_post_fields( 'http://itorrents.org/autoupload.php', array(), $files );
    $tmp = explode( "\r\n", $http_resp );
    $infoHash = substr( $tmp[count( $tmp ) - 1], 0, 40 );
    unset( $tmp, $http_resp, $files );
?>
```

This is what I have tried from one of the older StackOverflow posts, but with no luck so far.

```
function curl_upload($url,$fileFormAttribute,$file){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $post = array($fileFormAttribute=>"@".$file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return $response;
}
```

And then calling the function via: `curl_upload('http://itorrents.org/autoupload.php','torrent',"$ab_path/$linux_collection.torrent");`

**Edit:** The response I get is "Checking your browser before accessing itorrents.org" by Cloudflare when I click submit.
Then after that, it redirects to

```
mywebsite.com/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?s=really_long_number_string&jschl_vc=0ac4a596926c3da8c078dd235e8&pass=68203599.725-MBi81hLoVZ&jschl_answer=25.5352140140
```

which results in 404 not found.

Comment: You did not read the PHP manual regarding file uploads on php7.2+

Comment: Hi. Thanks but that didn't really help. Which part is incorrect? What is changed from 7.0 to 7.2 in terms of curl uploading? Which manual (Link if possible)? PS: The manual I read was https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php